# SDL_ttf linking errors Code::Blocks(Windows)

Tags: linker, sdl, codeblocks, sdl-ttf

I've followed tutorial from lazyfoo.net how to link SDL_ttf with Code::Blocks(windows), but something is wrong. I get these errors:

```
C:\SDL_ttf-2.0.11\include\SDL_ttf.h|30|error: SDL.h: No such file or directory|
C:\SDL_ttf-2.0.11\include\SDL_ttf.h|31|error: begin_code.h: No such file or directory|
C:\SDL_ttf-2.0.11\include\SDL_ttf.h|247|error: close_code.h: No such file or directory|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I just ported code to visual studio and downloaded SDL_tff for it and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

In SDL_ttf.h change

```
#include"SDL.h"
#include"begin_code.h"
#include"close_code.h"
```

to

```
#include<SDL/SDL.h>
#include<SDL/begin_code.h>
#include<SDL/close_code.h>
```